# How do I hide a field from a Profile2 form without deleting it?

Tags: entities, users

I have a field in a [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) form. I'm trying to streamline the signup process and not ask for users' phone numbers. However, I don't want to delete the phone numbers of users who have already inputted the field, so I don't want to delete the field.

How do I hide the field from the form, without deleting it, and having the ability to unhide it if I decide to do that later (or ask for the information at a later time, after initial signup)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the [Field Permissions Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions), and set it to admin only. It can easily be changed later to allow everyone to see the field.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.